# Creating an offcanvas navbar in bootstrap hides the nav-items in larger screen, why?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am designing a navbar for my website using bootstrap, Actually I want a offcanvas navbar that opens up right to left, I successfully achieved that but now the nav-items are not visible in the desktop view.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="pp.png" alt="..">
             </a>
           </div>
                

            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" tabindex="-1" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar" aria-controls="offcanvasNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon" data-bs-target="#offcanvasNavbar"></span>
              </button>

              <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end" id="offcanvasNavbar">
                <div class="offcanvas-header">
                  <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="offcanvas-body">
                <ul id = "nav-list" class="navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                  </li>
                 
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Events</a>
                  </li>
                 
                </ul>
              </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </nav>
```

Comment: Seems to work fine https://codeply.com/p/g27NEu7Rpg .. make sure you properly close the last `div` and `nav` as the code you posted isn't

Comment: I cannot find where the tag isn't closed, still doesn't work for me

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm facing the same thing now.